# Scalar and Vector Projections

Tags: vector

Find the scalar and vector projections of b onto a.
a=3i-3j+k b=2i+4j-k

The only function I could find was "Projection." Help?

Comment: Yep, that's the one to use.  See also `Norm` or `Dot`.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't give you the scalar or vector projections.

Comment: Like how would i do Dot over Norm for scalar projection?

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate use of[`Projection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Projection.html):

```
a = {3, -3, 1};
b = {2, 4, -1};
p = Projection[a, b]
Graphics3D[
 MapThread[{Text[Style[#3, 12], #2/2, {1, 1}], #1, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #2}]} &, {{Red, Blue, Green}, {a, b, p}, {"a", 
     "b", "projection"}}]~Join~{{Dashed, Arrow[{a, p}]}}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that but I need a sequence of operations that would give me the dot product of a and b divided by the Norm of a in to a numerical answer

Comment: @UYt  since you know the formula I suggest you look at the documentation and you will find it is a simple matter to code. Try and you will either resolve it yourself or edit your question with what you have tried and explaining what went wrong.  Good luck.